# Django printing many to many children not in same order as input

Tags: django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield, m2m

I have a `Tourguide` model with a many to many relationship with `Places`. Both models are defined as :

```
class Tourguide(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=255, blank=True)
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, db_column='placesdj')
    places_app = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='places')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_On', default = now)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tourguide'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Place(models.Model):
   place_id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   place_name = models.CharField(db_column='Place_Name', max_length=255)
   address_line_1 = models.CharField(db_column='Address_Line_1', max_length=255)
   address_line_2 = models.CharField(db_column='Address_Line_2', max_length=255)
   area = models.CharField(db_column='Area', max_length=255)


   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'Place'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.place_name
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When I try to print the `places` in a `tourguide` using :

```
{% for place in tour.places.all %}
    <tbody>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>id: {{place.place_id}}, {{ place.place_name }} </td>
    <td> {{ place.description }} </td>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

The order of the places is all random and not the same as the order I inputed it as. I want to print the places in the same order that I placed them in. My view for listing the tourguides and places within them is as so.

```
def tour_list(request, template_name='tourguides/tour_list.html'):
    tourguide_list = Tourguide.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(tourguide_list,6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    tourguides = paginator.get_page(page)
    data = {}
    data['tourguides'] = tourguides

    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

**Update**
I have an array of place id's in the tourguide table, is there a way i can use that?

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases do not sort rows by default, and since they are internally stored in all kinds of weird data structures, there is no "input order" either.

As a workaround, you can use the automatically generated `place_id` field as a sort key as it is pretty much guaranteed to go up as new entries are created. You can add a default sorting to your `Place` class, for example:

```
class Place(models.Model):
   ...

   class Meta:
       ...
       ordering = ('place_id',)
```

That would guarantee that any queries that will return a `Place` queryset will be ordered by `place_id` by default (i.e. unless you have an explicit `.order_by()` clause).

Comment: Im not sure if this would work, for example if I create a tourguide and I add places in order of [Place 3, Place 1, Place 10], 
Would your solution not just return [Place _1, Place_3, Place_10]
and not the order they were input in?

Comment: Why? Since `place_id` is an `AutoField` it would be `1` for `Place 3`, `2` for `Place 1` and `3` for `Place 10` (assuming that there were no previous records).

Comment: The places have already been created, they aren't new records being generated. So ordering by wouldm't work as it would just return them in the their ID order which is not the same as the input order

Comment: Did you assign `place_id`s manually instead of using the auto increment feature of your database? In that case there is nothing in that table that correlates to the input order.

Comment: No so the problem that arises from  adding ordering = ('place_id',) is that when you want to create a tourguide it will force the order of the places to be sorted by place_id aswell. is there a way to have it only order for when viewing the tourguide and not on input??

Comment: There is no "order" when you are creating a database record. The sorting is always performed when you make a query.